# Klibc: understanding memory allocation done for _IO_file_pvt struct

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, stdio, libc

In the `klibc` implementation of the C standard library. The `FILE` struct is defined as follows:

```
struct _IO_file {
    int _IO_fileno;     /* Underlying file descriptor */
    _Bool _IO_eof;      /* End of file flag */
    _Bool _IO_error;    /* Error flag */
};
typedef struct _IO_file FILE;

struct _IO_file_pvt {
    struct _IO_file pub;    /* Data exported to inlines */
    struct _IO_file_pvt *prev, *next;
    char *buf;      /* Buffer */
    char *data;     /* Location of input data in buffer */
    unsigned int ibytes;    /* Input data bytes in buffer */
    unsigned int obytes;    /* Output data bytes in buffer */
    unsigned int bufsiz;    /* Total size of buffer */
    enum _IO_bufmode bufmode; /* Type of buffering */
};
```

The allocation done for this struct:

```
struct _IO_file_pvt *f;
const size_t bufoffs =
    (sizeof *f + 4*sizeof(void *) - 1) &
    ~(4*sizeof(void *) - 1);

f = zalloc(bufoffs + BUFSIZ + _IO_UNGET_SLOP);
```

Where `BUFSIZ` is 16K and `_IO_UNGET_SLOP` 32.

The `buf` field points to an address after the struct itself, that is why during the allocation an extra `BUFSIZ + _IO_UNGET_SLOP` is needed.

What I do not understand is why `bufoffs` is defined that way. Wouldn't `sizeof *f` be enough?

I tested the expression on both 32 bit and 64 machines. `sizeof *f` is 40 and 56 bytes, respectively. `bufoffs` is 48 and 64 bytes. Meaning it is adding 8 bytes in both cases. I suspect it's for memory alignment purposes but I'm not sure. And even if it is, why is it needed?

Comment: Is there a developer mailing list for klibc? It might be better asking the developers. Or maybe compare to something like uclibc?

Comment: I get 48 for bufoffs on 32-bit machines with (40 + 15) & ~15, am I missing anything?

Comment: My bad, it is indeed 48. Meaning on both systems it adds 8 bytes after the end of the struct.

Comment: There is a [klibc mailing list](http://www.zytor.com/mailman/listinfo/klibc).  It looks to me like the code is aligning the buffer to a pointer size.  `klibc` is *minimal* so the allocator might not have all the bells and whistles you are use to; an allocator is smaller if all the callers align their buffers by a compile time calculation.  `klibc` is not *fast*, it is not *portable*, it is a small minimum to get Linux to boot via an `initramfs`.